# use of a comma before the conjunction "plus"

Tags: conjunctions

> Sweet children enjoy sprinkles on top of ice cream sundaes, plus the syrups at the bottom of the dish.

Would this be correct without the comma?

Comment: When you say 'after' do you mean 'before'?

Comment: The sentence doesn't seem balanced: why _sprinkles_ (implying optionality) but _the syrups_ (implying inevitability)?

Comment: The author is trying to picture the enjoyment of an ice cream sundae. First the sprinkles demand complete attention; finally only the syrup is left. That *optional* comma extends the sentence fractionally. It separates two scenes.

Comment: Yes it's fine.  You could substitute "and" for the "plus," and I hope you can see there would not be a comma after "plus."  In point of fact, you don't need the comma before "plus" because it's in the middle of a two-part parallel construction.

Answer (score 0):

*Plus* used this way is a conjunction, such as *and* or *or*; you do not put a comma after the conjunction.

Comment: Hello, user 133296. OP has almost certainly erred in her question. Also, [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plus) is far less sure about the word class for this usage, labelling it **conj., adv. prep.** ...  2. in addition to: to have wealth plus fame. (1. increased by: Ten plus two is twelve.) I'd use _, and_ here to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is really saying children enjoy **both** sprinkles and syrups, which are separated physically (the sprinkles are on the top, the syrups are on the bottom).

Without the comma the sentence does not make sense, 'plus' is used in place of 'and' here.

Commas belong where a person would pause in speaking, the sentence is too long without a comma, so the comma should separate the two phrases. The second phrase is 'the syrups at the bottom of the dish'.

Removing the comma would imply the icecream sundaes were at the the bottom of the dish, along with the syrups, which would be confusing because the sprinkles then something else would be on top of the ice-cream.

User133296 is correct that the comma would never go after plus/and/or etc.

(The real issue with the sentence is the use of **Sweet children** - sweet in behavior/nature is being combined with sugary (sweet tasting) food.)

Comment: 'Commas belong where a person would pause in speaking' conflicts with '[It] is correct that a comma would never go after _plus/and/or_ etc'. Sometimes, a dramatic pause is inserted after an _and_ / _or_ ....

Comment: In the context of ice-cream sundaes a dramatic pause would not be needed (!) English has many exceptions, so many in fact that **the exception makes the rule**

Comment: Never say 'Never;' here is an example of commas **following** conjunctions from a Grammar site:   http://grammarist.com/grammar/conjunctions/  *and,* *because,* *but,* *for,* *nor,* *so,* *until,* *when,* and *yet.*

Comment: @Hugh: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-mention_distinction. The commas are not following *conjunctions*, but *mentions* of conjunctions. Mentions function as nouns.

Comment: "In the context of ice-cream sundaes a dramatic pause would not be needed (!) English has many exceptions, so many in fact that the exception makes the rule." But you make a generalised statement: "Commas belong where a person would pause in speaking" without qualifying it in your answer. // Here, I'd use the disambiguating comma, as with 'I'd like bacon and eggs, and trifle'. It does mirror the 'pause' rule-of-thumb in this case. // I'd not use 'plus' here at all.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence should be rewritten, as it is unclear to begin with.  A comma will not rescue it.

My suggestion: "Children enjoy sprinkles on top of ice cream sundaes.  They also enjoy the syrup."

Is it necessary to say where the syrup is?  What are you trying to convey to the reader?  Is it necessary to say they enjoy both sprinkles and syrup?

If you prefer to keep your version, then the comma is necessary to avoid ambiguity.